# Difference between wireless user group and wireless mesh network?

Tags: wireless-networking

What is the difference between a Wireless User Group and a Wireless Mesh Network?

[wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesh_networking) says a wireless mesh network is a community network where `each node must not only capture and disseminate its own data, but also serve as a relay for other nodes, that is, it must collaborate to propagate the data in the network.`

I don't understand what this means. Can you please explain it in Layman's terms?

I'm trying to suggest a way to build a local community network to a person. It's not supposed to require any internet access thus it should be free (People should be able to play games with each other, share resources and host websites on the network). Am I looking for a wireless user group or wireless mesh network?

Comment: What is the purpose of the network you are trying to create?

Comment: It's mainly supposed to be a sort of substitution for the internet for distribution of open-source material in a place where internet connectivity is expensive

Answer (score 2):

I believe the difference you're looking for is this:

A wireless mesh network is anyone connected to the network who can receive, transmit and relay data to everyone else on the network.

A wireless user group is a group of individuals who belong to a subnet of the wireless mesh network that only talk to each other and ignore everyone else in the wireless mesh network.

If it helps, think of it as the difference between a park and a country club.  A park anyone can join, a country club is by invitation only.

Comment: So wireless mesh networks need not provide internet access, they may just allow communication between connected users?